# iOSアプリのAdMob広告を子供向けに設定したい。

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

子供向けのアプリを製作し、AdMobで収益化を図ろうとしたのですが、
子供向けフラグを立ててアプリをAppleの審査に提出したところ、

Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category
（ガイドライン1.3 - 安全性 - キッズカテゴリー）

の部分で審査を却下されました。
要約すると以下のようなものです。

１、子供向けに不適切なコンテンツを表示する広告がアプリに含まれています。
２、タップすると、ユーザーをWebページやApp Storeに誘導する広告が含まれています。

どうやら子供向けとして配信する必要があるようでした。
そこで、下記のページを参考にして、子供向けタグの設定を行いました。

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6219315?hl=ja

```
let request = GADRequest()
var components = DateComponents()
let time = timeGetYear()  //現在の年(2018)
components.month = 1
components.day = 1
components.year = time-6  //6歳
req.birthday = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
request.tag(forChildDirectedTreatment: true)
```

しかし配信される広告に変化はなく、一応改めて審査に提出しましたが、先と同様に却下されてしまいました。

そのほかに必要な設定の変更などがあるかどうかなど調べてみましたが、情報が出てきません。

子供向けの広告を配信し、広告をタップした後、遷移の確認を挟んだのちにURLのページに飛ぶといった広告を見たことがあるので、そういった広告を出す必要があるのだと思います。

ほかの広告会社を利用するなどを含め、解決法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

開発環境
Xcode9.2 Swift4.0.3

Comment: コード読む限り、リクエストにターゲットの生年月日を含んだりしないといけなかったりしませんか？　そのコードのように生年月日を含まない場合のデフォルト値のせいでターゲットに常に成人扱いになっててないですか

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。子供向け設定の部分しか見ていなくて、生年月日の方を見落としていました。今生年月日を追加して見ましたが、今のところ広告の種類は変わっていないように思います。設定が反映されるまで時間がかかるとも書かれているので、少し様子を見てみようと思います。

Comment: 誕生日を2011年（6歳）にして設定し、改めて審査に出してみましたが、同じく却下されてしまいました。

Comment: 同じ理由でのリジェクトですか？　異議申し立てはしてみましたか？　「広告が全年齢向けではないことが原因と思い、広告が全年齢向けになるよう修正した。それ以外になにが原因ですか」と。きちんと説明すると修正部分の有効性が認められて通る話も聞きます。あと、誕生日の設定は、固定だと数年後に子供向け以外の広告が配信される状態だから、広告の生成時に現在時間をとり、4歳以上向けのアプリなら4年引くみたいな動的なものにしたほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: あと、じぶんもAdMobを考えていていずれ同じ問題に当たりそうなので、同じ環境で試したいです（テストなのでApp Storeには提出しませんが）。XcodeのバージョンとiOSのサポート下限を教えてくださいませんか

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。リジェクト理由は変わっていません。異議申し立ては今のところしていませんが、スクリーンショットを添付されて適切じゃない広告が出ていると言われているので、どう言ったらいいのかわからない状態です…。あと、これは説明不十分だったかもしれませんが、リジェクト理由は二つあって、一つは「子供向けでない広告が表示される」ということで、もう一つは「タップすると、ユーザーをWebページやApp Storeに誘導する広告が含まれている」ということでした。ほかの子供向けアプリで　広告をタップ-> リンクに飛ぶ確認-> 遷移　という広告を見たことがあるので、前者を満たすことで後者も満たされると思っていましたが、どうなのでしょうか。自分の広告をタップすることはできないのでこればかりは確認ができません...。それとXcode9.2  iOSサポート10.0 です。

Comment: なるほど。審査側でもこども向け以外の広告が表示されたままなんですね。広告からの遷移が不適切とされるのは、たぶんペアレンタルゲートが必要なんだと思います。こどもが広告をクリックした場合、親の同意なしにその先のページを開かせないやつで、親にアプリ内で設定させたパスワードなどを入力させるなどして承認してもらうものです。